# navigator.permissions.query на iOS

Tags: javascript, ios

Есть код

```
navigator.permissions.query({name:'geolocation'}).then(function(result) {
  if (result.state === 'granted') {
    getLocation();
  } else if (result.state === 'prompt') {
    console.log('не решено');
  } else{
    getLocation();
  }
  // Don't do anything if the permission was denied.
});
```

Суть в том, что мы смотрим, разрешена ли геолокация для сайта. Если да - грузим данные в блок, если нет - в блоке есть кнопка "разрешить доступ к положению". Сделано, чтоб при загрузке сайта не пугать пользователя запросами. Беда в том, что `navigator.permissions.query` не работает на iOS. Как проверить разрешен ли доступ к геолокации сайту на iOS?